# HTML Canvas toDataURL upload not working on iOS mobile

Tags: ios, file, canvas, mobile-safari

I have this problem of uploading base64 data to my server. I first convert base64 data to blob and create a new file with File API which is then uploaded to the server. The problem is that, this solution works in chrome both on desktop and mobile but not on iOS Mobile Safari(latest version). My flow looks like below.

canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg') --> base64 --> blob --> File

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return new Blob([ab], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
}

var base64 = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.8)
var file = new File([dataURItoBlob(base64)], "filename")
/* Standard ajax uploading goes here */
```

After uploading, I got only small white blank square on iOS, but it works fine in Chrome on both mobile and desktop.

So my question is, why isn't uploading on iOS working?

Comment: Try to not use `new File`, instead, if your *Standard ajax uploading*  missing part includes a FormData like I believe, use `formData.append('file', dataURItoBlob(base64), filename);` Safari did implement File constructor not so long ago, and still have quirks.